# HTTP errors, can I return data other than HTML?

Tags: html, http, error-handling

I want to confirm that I can return an image or a CSS file when I generate a 403 error.

From the documentation, it sounds like I can, as per: `any included representation` from section 6.5.

> 6.5. Client Error 4xx
>
> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
> seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.  These status codes are applicable to any request method.
> User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5

Would you agree that we do not have to return HTML on a 403 error?

Comment: Wow @nsinreal calm down

Comment: @nsinreal, I find the documentation not so clear about it... also I searched Stackoverflow and it looks like the question wasn't raised yet. So that's either that everyone else but me knew the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to return something else than HTML for an error.

Image hosts sometimes return errors as images so they would show up when embedded with `<img>`. Web APIs will often return an error description as JSON/XML. So it's not only perfectly fine, but also common.

Comment: That was exactly my idea. Right now my CMS returns HTML and I am looking into return data that is defined by the type of request. That way images will show a GIF with an error such as "not found" or "not available". Otherwise those images just look broken and it takes time to think: let's test that image to see the error. Thank you for the confirmation.